# MonoTouch: tmp folder location?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Using the .NET framework in MonoTouch, how do I get to the /tmp folder ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will return your app's tmp folder

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```